# Persistent MongoDB Connection With Django

Tags: django, mongodb

I am currently using (or hoping to use) both PostgreSQL and MongoDB for my Django project. When it comes to MongoDB I've been looking at PyMongo to make the connection, and add/edit info using Python. Most likely I will be calling PyMongo in my `views.py` to read/insert/edit data from MongoDB.

For the sake of this question, let's say I have a view called `worksheet`, which querys some data from MongoDB relevant to the current user. However I would like to maintain a persistent connection to the database so that I do not have to make a new connection every time a user visits the `worksheet` view.

Is there any way I could make a persistent connection so I am not wasting time/resources making new connections to MongoDB every time? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the exact same thing and this is how I did it.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from threading import local
from django.conf import settings

_mongo_client = local()
def mongo_client():
    client = getattr(_mongo_client, 'client', None)
    if client is None:
        client = MongoClient(settings.MONGODB_URI)
        _mongo_client.client = client
    return client
```

And then in your views you use it the client like this.

```
mongo_client().db.orders.find(...)
```

This is what I have been doing and it works, my only concern would be if the mongodb client correctly reestablishes lost connections... But I think it does because I have not been having any issues.